# Replacing winlogon.exe in windows embedded

Tags: windows, visual-c++, embedded, windows-embedded

I need to create my own UI for windows login. I'm doing this using Windows 7 Embedded and I have complete access to image creation and modification.

From researching I've learnt that winlogon.exe is called by smss.exe  I've haven't looked too much into smss.exe; I've started to disassemble it, but I haven't quite found out how it launches winlogon.  I think, and I hope that this information is contained somewhere in the registry, otherwise it may cause conflicts with windows updates.

I'm also starting to get a grasp of the hierarchy of windows sessions, stations, and desktops.  <s>One thing that is curious to me is that winlogon runs on session 1.  I would have assumed it would be running on session 0, but this is not the case.  Does this mean that a new instance of winlogon is spawned for each user session?</s>
**Edit: I now know that a winlogon instance is created for each user**

In essence I'm trying to figure out where I go from here.  Now that I have a somewhat limited grasp on user sessions, how do I begin implementing my custom logon user interface.

Any help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After billions of Google searches I finally found where to begin.  What I want to do is write a custom GINA.  I found this [article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163803.aspx) on MSDN that explains the process.

**Edit: Credential Providers have replaced GINA in Windows Vista and above.  An overview is found [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163489.aspx)**.

Comment: Seems like you have solved your problem; it's fine to accept your own answer.  Some might say wait a bit, but it doesn't seem like your question has had much attention from others so you don't have to delay.  Do come back and review anything additional if it gets posted though.